# VBulletin URL Redirect after Switch Back To Old Structure

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Have removed VBSEO as it caused havoik to my forums and it continues to do so.

My present URL structure is this:

http://www.thessdreview.com/Forums/showthread.php?t=3862

The problem is original links were created as this which now return as a 404:

http://www.thessdreview.com/Forums/ssd-benchmark-locker/3862.htm

1. Can you suggest a way to get these thousands of indexed urls to work again through a .htaaccess fix?